# Access to UIViewController from a random class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to find solution how to access to a `UIViewcontroller` from a random class in my project.

Before I was doing in my class:

```
MBViewController vc =  (MBViewController *)[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
```

It worked well.

Now I changed the `rootViewController` "I'm using the `MainVC` class of the `AMSlidMenu` as `rootview`" so this path is not available anymore.

Can someone help me please.

Comment: Not enough info. How are you creating this view controller? In general terms, you should save a pointer to it when it's created. A singleton is a decent place to save app-global data - better than the app delegate.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this. Better would be to pass the viewController to the objects that need access to it.

Comment: yes @DanielT. but if every time my MBViewController is used i lose my old data that i display on it.
The best way i guess is to do singleton in my MBViewController no ?

Comment: If you are loosing data on your VC every time you use it, then that is your problem. Making the VC globally available won't solve that.

Comment: Plasher gave a good idea :  .. delegate] window] vc]; but i cant get it the vc cuz he is not declared in the UIWindow interface :s

Comment: It's the same answer I gave you the last time you asked the question. Create the view controller in the app delegate and then you can access it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access to UIViewController from random class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764201/access-to-uiviewcontroller-from-random-class)

Comment: yes i did, but when i call it from other class, i will have the current MBViewController ? or a new reference ?

Comment: Please don't delete questions just because you don't like answers or comments, as you made it impossible for Paul now to receive reputation for his effort.

Answer (score 0):

You could create that ViewController as a property in your AppDelegate. Then you will be able to access it from anywhere using (thus it's not the most programmatically correct form)

```
MBViewController vc =  (MBViewController *)[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] _viewController];
```

Comment: thank you i tried 

    MBViewController *vc =  (MBViewController *)[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] _viewController];

Comment: but he dont find for me _viewController and i created as property in my AppDelegate

Comment: answer edited, its not window but just delegate.Try now

Comment: it doesnt work too the compilation error is no Know instance method for selector '_viewController'

Comment: vc = ((MBAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate)._viewController;

it tried this, it work, but i guess i still have to do a singleton on my ViewController

Comment: It should work thats the way, maybe a little try and test will do it

Comment: yes but, i just want to know if it give the current viewController or a new reference ? every time i call it

Comment: Should be the same viewController everytime

Comment: nop :( i have a method in my viewController to add data into a uitableView when he do reload data nothing happen. i cant see the data in the view. so i guess its a reference